# Using special characters within php echo

Tags: php

i use an if function to display copy but this copy has to be wrapped in double quotes, and i cant get it working. any help please.

**Code**

```
 $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($currentpage == "/room/penthouse-suite/"){
echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>"test penthouse"</div>";
}
```

so on my page it should display ---> **"test penthouse"**

Comment: just escape special characters by using a slash like \"test penthouse\"

Comment: that should have thrown you a parse error but you didn't have that setup to catch / display / log.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you maybe send me a link to a better explanation, just so i can check into this, im new so like to learn.

Comment: *there you go* http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php. Also `"` is a double quote, not a parenthesis.

Comment: `echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>" . '"' . test penthouse" . '"' . </div>";` Is one way

Comment: @chris85 I made the correction

Comment: NICE!!! thanks so much will do my research!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply escape the characters by using a backslash.

```
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($currentpage == "/room/penthouse-suite/"){
    echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>\"test penthouse\"</div>";
}
```

Comment: No problem @Ylama have fun building :)